# Making a string say what character comes next

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in programming and I have a doubt.
How do I make for the "cout" say what character comes next?

f.e. the string is "Hello World"
I choose "e" to be the character
then it should say "The next character is "l";
but instead it shows me the same character.

```
char s;
char letra;
string input = "";


cout << "Write a phrase: ";
getline(cin, input);
cout << "Insert a Character: ";
cin >> letra;
cout << "The Next character is:" << letra++;`
```

Comment: You can add your code to the post itself instead of linking a picture.

Comment: Please put your code in the question itself.  Pictures of code are notoriously hard to edit and compile.

Comment: Pictures of code cannot be consumed by the blind or hard of sight. And in case you thought there were no such people on Stack Overflow, you were mistaken.

Comment: @n.m. God that freehand red circle is beautiful

Comment: You've been downvoted because of question markup, but your code is wrong on many levels anyway. Please check out some tutorials first. Small hint: `letra` does not aware of the prior string at all.

Comment: You need to find the index of `letra`. [std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) or a simple loop.

Comment: Did you notice ...  There is no 'E' in "Hello World"?  So what would you want for output?

Comment: `x++` post increments. That is it changes the value AFTER using it. If you put in 'A', the program will print 'A' and then increment 'A' to 'B' (assuming a sane, sequential character encoding). There is no magic linking variables together, so you'll have to find the input character in the input string and then increment the location in the string. Watch out for the last character in the string.

Comment: You are not searching the `input` string. `letra` is whatever letter the user enters, then you output it *as-is* (then increment it to the next letter in the *alphabet*, not in the `input` string). Try something like this: `char letra; string input; cout << "Write a phrase: "; getline(cin, input); cout << "Write a Character: "; cin >> letra; size_t index = input.find(letra); if (index == string::npos) { cout << "Character not found"; } else if (index == (input.length()-1)) { cout << "Character is at the end"; } else { cout << "The Next character is: '" << input[index+1]; << "'" }`

Answer (score 0):

You can check with a for loop with the length of "**input**" and check if the char you entered **letra** equals the letter with i index for example if its equal print the letter with i+1 index in the input and then break.